# Using SED to remove line from textfile

Tags: bash, sed, line

I had a look around the internet for a line of code which would delete the whole line it found a match on.. So if it found file in the file below it would delete the whole file line.. i.e '13382748 | /root/file', which it does in the console...

/root/file:

```
13382748 | /root/file
13382749 | /root/test
```

The command below works in the console (as stated above) but does not work when running the script.

```
sed --in-place '/$number/d' /root/file
```

It is the last piece to finally complete my script. The line of code simply does nothing..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quotes prevent variable expansion.  Say:

```
sed --in-place "/$number/d" /root/file
```